# Haar analysis decay rate

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, wavelets

### Question

Prove the partial Haar sum $P_M(f_N)$, defined by $P_M(f_N)=\sum_{0\leq j < M} Q_j(f_N)+P_0(f_N)$, decays exponentially in $M: ||f_N-P_M(f_N)||_{L^2([0,1))} = 2^{-M/2}$, where $f_N=2^N\chi_{[0,2^{-N}]}$.

$P_j$ is the expectation operator and $Q_j$ is the difference operator defined accordingly. The interval we talked about here are all dyadic intervals.
\begin{equation*}
    P_jf(x):=\frac{1}{|I_j|}\int_{I_j}f(t)dt,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    Q_jf(x):=P_{j+1}f(x)-P_jf(x),
\end{equation*}

### My idea

Calculate the Haar coefficients first, but
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    <f_N,h_I> &= \int_I 2^N\chi_{[0,2^{-N}]} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|I|}}(\chi_{I_r}(x)-\chi_{I_l}(x)) dx = \frac{2^{N+1}}{\sqrt{|I|}} \int_{[2^{-N-1},2^{-N}]}\chi_{I_r}(x) dx
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
and I am not sure how to simplify this Haar coefficients. There's no certain conditions given on the dyadic interval. But then I tried

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        ||f_N-P_M(f_N)||_{L^2([0,1))} &= ||f_N-\sum_{0\leq j < M} Q_j(f_N)-P_0(f_N)||_{L^2([0,1))} \\
        &= ||f_N - P_{M+1}f_N||_{L^2([0,1))} \\
        &=  ||f_N - 2^{-M-1}\int_{I_{M+1}}f(t)dt||_{L^2([0,1))} 
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where I got stuck again since I am not sure how to deal with the integral with a dyadic interval.

Comment: Sorry. What is $Q_j$?

Comment: oh, that is the difference operator. Let me edit my question and you could find the definition up there.